# Behringer UCA202 Audio Interface and BEHRINGER C-1

Tags: microphone, audio-interfaces

I need to be able to use a BEHRINGER C-1 mic in my PC, I need to know if a Behringer UCA202 Audio Interface will work for me, if you know any other interface that would help me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't work. You will need a audiointerface with a phantom-powered XLR-input. I always recommend a better interface with good mic preamp for a clean record. The Focusrite Saffire 6 USB is a very nice interface for a good price.
Hope this answer is helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

This one is bad for a mic use (no XLR and Mic preamps).

To stay in a low price range (a bit higher than the UCA202 though) you should prefer this kind of interface.

[Scarlett Solo](http://www.thomann.de/fr/focusrite_scarlett_solo.htm?gclid=CMO71u3PzMkCFQT4wgodkXkOfQ)